# magento2.2 - programmatically create coupon

Tags: magento2, php, coupon

in a magento 2.2 based site we need to programmatically create a coupon code for . However was only able to find one code sample and it does not seem to work. Meaning no coupon code is created and when I look in the exception.log file I see the below error message

> main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined property: Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template::$objectManager in /var/www/html/****.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 110 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0):

Below is the code I am trying to use. Also as a side note the coupon code is created in the admin panel as a cart price rule.

```
//lets create a coupon code
$coupon['name'] = 'vip_signup';
$coupon['desc'] = 'Discount for vip signup.';
$coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
$coupon['end'] = '';
$coupon['max_redemptions'] = '1';
$coupon['discount_type'] ='by_percent';
$coupon['discount_amount'] ='15';
$coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
$coupon['redemptions'] = '1';
$coupon['code'] ='NL01-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenetated but i am hard coding for testing purposes


$shoppingCartPriceRule = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');

$shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
        ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
        ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
        ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
        ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
        ->setIsActive('1')
        ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
        ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
        ->setDiscountQty(1)
        ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
        ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
        ->setWebsiteIds(array('1',))
        ->setCouponType('2')
        ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);

return $shoppingCartPriceRule->save();
       $shoppingCartPriceRule->unsetData();
```

Comment: coupon code is generated using above code, there are not issue related to couponcode

Comment: You can refer a link, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-coupon-code-programmatically-magento-2/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create `CouponCode.php` file at magento root and add below code in this file. After run this file in browser and check admin side.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; 

/**
 * If your external file is in root folder
 */
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
//$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');  


$coupon['name'] = 'vip_signup';
$coupon['desc'] = 'Discount for vip signup coupon.';
$coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
$coupon['end'] = '';
$coupon['max_redemptions'] = 1;
$coupon['discount_type'] ='by_percent';
$coupon['discount_amount'] = 15;
$coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
$coupon['redemptions'] = 1;
$coupon['code'] ='NL01-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenetated but i am hard coding for testing purposes

$shoppingCartPriceRule = $obj->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
$shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
        ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
        ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
        ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
        ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
        ->setIsActive(1)
        ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
        ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
        ->setDiscountQty(1)
        ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
        ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
        ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
        ->setCouponType(2)
        ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);
$shoppingCartPriceRule->save();
```

**OR**

User below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
//$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');  


$coupon['name'] = 'vip_signup';
$coupon['desc'] = 'Discount for vip signup coupon.';
$coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
$coupon['end'] = '';
$coupon['max_redemptions'] = 1;
$coupon['discount_type'] ='by_percent';
$coupon['discount_amount'] = 15;
$coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
$coupon['redemptions'] = 1;
$coupon['code'] ='NL01-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenetated but i am hard coding for testing purposes

$shoppingCartPriceRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
$shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
        ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
        ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
        ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
        ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
        ->setIsActive(1)
        ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
        ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
        ->setDiscountQty(1)
        ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
        ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
        ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
        ->setCouponType(2)
        ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);
$shoppingCartPriceRule->save();
```

Comment: Thank you this works. How could this code be modified to just create a coupon code in an existing cart price rule?

Comment: Try this: $objectManager = $oldCouponCode = 'NL01-1234';
$newCouponCode = 'NL01-12345';
$couponModel = $obj->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon')->load($oldCouponCode, 'code');
if($couponModel->getRuleId()) {
 $shoppingCartPriceRule = $obj->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->load($couponModel->getRuleId());
 $shoppingCartPriceRule->setCouponCode($newCouponCode);
 $shoppingCartPriceRule->save();
}

Comment: What if I have to create only for single product id.

Comment: @urfusion Are you needed with coupon code or auto apply discount in single product?

Comment: I wanted to apply coupon code only on specific products only. Anyway I have done that. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @urfusion Yes it is possible

Comment: Try this : $shoppingCartPriceRule->setProductIds(array(1,2,3));

Comment: @Abdul i have used your code $shoppingCartPriceRule->setProductIds(array(1,2,3)); for specific product only but its not working for me. Thanks for your response

Comment: @Abdul i want to create coupon code for specific rule can you help me.

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari Sure :) Can u please explain you logic for specific rule

Comment: i have one rule id 117 i want to create coupon after successful order under rule id 117 every time

Comment: @urfusion Sir did you set the *coupon* for the specific products if yes can you please tell me `$shoppingCartPriceRule->setProductIds(array(1,2,3));` this code is not working for me

Comment: @AsadKhan : Please check the code
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ml66zotfwtarxlu/CouponCode.php?dl=0

Comment: @urfusion as per my understanding you can get product Ids from configuration if it is true can you please explain me the whether you are getting **multiple product ids** or **single product Id** in the code below `$coupon['product_ids'] = $couponData['general']['product_id'] ;`

Comment: @AsadKhan : I create a small module which have fields to enter sku in backend.

Comment: @urfusion so sir you add in this line `$coupon['product_ids'] = $couponData['general']['product_id'] ;` **SKU** ??? or you add the product ID?

Comment: Can you please Send me the **Configuration** Screenshot???

Comment: How can I use coupon on the bases of timer

Answer (score 0):

Using below code, Cart coupon is generated for magento 2.2 and there are not any issue related to coupon code.

Coupon code is generated using below code fine,

**please add before line with $objectmanager declaration,**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Your final code,

```
$coupon['name'] = 'vip_signup';
$coupon['desc'] = 'Discount for vip signup coupon.';
$coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
$coupon['end'] = '';
$coupon['max_redemptions'] = '1';
$coupon['discount_type'] ='by_percent';
$coupon['discount_amount'] ='15';
$coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
$coupon['redemptions'] = '1';
$coupon['code'] ='NL01-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenetated but i am hard coding for testing purposes

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$shoppingCartPriceRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');

$shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
        ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
        ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
        ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
        ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
        ->setIsActive('1')
        ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
        ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
        ->setDiscountQty(1)
        ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
        ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
        ->setWebsiteIds(array('1',))
        ->setCouponType('2')
        ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);

$shoppingCartPriceRule->save();
```

> main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined property:
>   Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template::$objectManager in
>   /var/www/html/****.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php
>   on line 110 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0):

**For issue you faced is related to Your Porto Theme and not related to above coupon code so please verify your theme or might be check using default luma theme and just disable your current Porto Theme.**

Comment: What if I have to create only for single product id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not initialized $objectManager in your code, add following before using objectmanager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

or use dependency injection for the same.