# Magento 2. How to Generate Coupon for specific product / products Programmatically

Tags: magento2, backend, coupon

I want to generate the coupon for the specific products like I want to generate the coupon for the **product with id= 20** whose price is let suppose **30$** and I want to sell it on **15$**. How can I generate this **programmatically**? thanks in Advance

Comment: Refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207311/magento2-2-programmatically-create-coupon. Go to comments of answer, where you can find this line $shoppingCartPriceRule->setProductIds(array(1,2,3)); for specific product's coupon code.

Comment: @DharaBhatti I'm not getting where is this line $shoppingCartPriceRule->setProductIds(array(1,2,3)); and what about the price limit like I want to fix the price for specific product I dont want to set the price by % I want to set the price fix like one product price is 30$ and I want to set this product price to 20$ fix how can I do this?

Comment: Then you have to use $coupon['discount_type'] ='by_fixed'; instead of $coupon['discount_type'] ='by_percent'; And for this line $shoppingCartPriceRule->setProductIds(array(1,2,3));, click on "show 6 more comments" in the comments area of answer.

Comment: @DharaBhatti can you please help me how to get this coupon number in other file actually I want to send this coupon number in email to customer.

Comment: First get rule_id using Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon class by your coupon code and then load that rule using Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule class by rule_id. You will get details about your coupon code that you added.

Comment: @DharaBhatti can you also please sort out these problems for me?

1) how can I test this code that is it working or not .

2) Where to create this code in my module in which folder I need to create this

Comment: 1) how can I test this code that is it working or not . -
 Please any product to cart and got to cart page. You can see a Discount Code text box, enter your newly added coupon code in that text box and click on Apply. If it works perfectly, then its working fine.
2) Where to create this code in my module in which folder I need to create - 
 You can create a controller for this code with 2 options, one is if that controller is for one time use, then run that controller and put die(); at end of the script. An the other option if that controller is used for multi purpose then use it as AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at Last I solve this mystery we cannot apply the coupon on the specific product by using `getProductIds()` to apply the coupon on the specific product we have to add few conditions after the basic coupon code

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule;
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $helpercontext,
    Rule $rule,
 ){
    $this->_rule = $rule;
    parent::__construct($helpercontext);
 }
 public function setCoupon()
{
    // $this->_state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');  
    // $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend');  


    $coupon['name'] = 'Offer_asad2';
    $coupon['desc'] = 'Discount for vip signup coupon.';
    $coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
    $coupon['end'] = '';
    $coupon['max_redemptions'] = 1;
    $coupon['discount_type'] ='by_fixed';
    $coupon['discount_amount'] = 15;
    $coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
    $coupon['redemptions'] = 1;
    $coupon['code'] ='NL04-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenerated but i am hard coding for testing purposes  

    $this->_rule->setName($coupon['name'])
            ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
            ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
            ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
            ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
            ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
            ->setIsActive(1)
            ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
            ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
            ->setDiscountQty(1)
            ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
            ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
            ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
            ->setCouponType(2)
            // ->setProductIds(array(1,2,3))
            // ->setProductIds(array('1','2','3'))
            ->setProductIds(1)
            ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
            ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);
           $conditions["1"] = array
                (
                "type" => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine",
                "aggregator" => "all",
                "attribute" => null,
                "operator" => null,
                "value" => 1,
                "is_value_processed" => null,
            );
            $conditions["1--1"] = array
                (
                "type" => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found",
                "attribute" => null,
                "operator" => null,
                "value" => 1,
                "is_value_processed" => null,
                "aggregator" => "all",
            );
            $conditions["1--1--1"] = array
                (
                "type" => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
                "attribute" => "sku",
                "operator" => "==",
                // "operator" => "()",
                // "value" => $couponData['general']['product_id']
                "value" => $this->getSKUU(),
            );
            $conditions["1--1--1-1"] = array
                (
                "type" => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
                // "attribute" => "quote_item_row_total",
                "attribute" => "quote_item_qty",
                "operator" => "==",
                "value" => 1
            );

            $actions = array(
                "1" => array(
                        "type"          => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
                        "aggregator"    => "all",
                        "value"         => "1",
                        "new_child"     => false
                ),
                "1--1" => array(
                        "type"          => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
                        "attribute"     => "sku",
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value' => $this->getSKUU()
                )
            );

    $this->_rule->save();
}
```