# How to use Coupon in magento 2

Tags: magento2, backend, coupon

I create a **Coupon code** from 
[magento2.2 - programmatically create coupon](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207311/magento2-2-programmatically-create-coupon?noredirect=1&lq=1) this code now I have some questions

**1)** how can I test this code that is it working or not .

**2)** How can I get this coupon code like I want to send this code in Email to customer .

**3)** How can I fix the price of the specific product like let suppose one product price is 30$ n I want to fix that product price to 15$.

**4)** And How can I apply this on specific Product.

**5)** Where to create this code in my module in which folder I need to create this

Comment: Could you please share your code too..

Comment: @GeeEmm dear I just give you the link as well I just write the links code in my module you can search that