# Magento v2 -> Buy an item (virtual) and get voucher code via E-mail

Tags: magento2, order-email, virtual-products

I have a question regarding Magento v 2.
Do you know (default or addon) a functionality to have a virtual item (lets say, 100 dollar voucher) and after the customer's check-out he gets directly an email sent with voucher code?

Thank you!

Rosi

Comment: Hey, I think the best way to do that is using an observer after the order is placed, check if the order total are higher than let's say those 100 and if they are create a coupon code programmatically, after that create an email template and send to customer with the code. To create the coupon can check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/207844/86398, as for the observer you can try sales_order_save_after. I don't think Magento as that out of the box and extension you can check this one https://marketplace.magento.com/folio3ecommerce-module-orderemailcoupons.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you should go with the gift card product concept, not a virtual product. You can use this free extension.

https://store.magenest.com/magento-2/gift-card.html

Please let me know if this will not help.

Nitish